# Words for "Those who pass / fail in an exam."

Tags: word-request

I know:

Those who **win**: **Winner**

Those who **lose**: **Loser**

But,

Those who **fail** in an exam: **?**

And,

Those who **pass** in an exam: **?**

Please help.

Thank you.

(Edited after jonathanjo's comment)

Answer (score 1):

It's not common usage, but those who **pass** or **fail** an exam would be **passers** or **failers**.

We would be much more likely to use your phrase people **who pass/passed** and those **who fail/failed**.  There are also **success** and **failure**, which can mean either the abstract concept or an individual.  Out of context, however, to call someone a success or failure means "failure in life" not "failure in their exam" and sounds very judgemental.

As it's often a sensitive matter, you will often hear other softer phrases: those **who didn't pass** or **weren't successful**.

For an exam you can sit as many times as you want, sometimes **weren't successful yet**.  For an exam which is marked in grades which don't actually have "fail", people will often say **didn't get good grades**.  For example, UK 'A' Level exams can be used as entrance exams for university, and if you don't get the grades you need for your chosen university, you'd say "I didn't get the grades I needed/wanted".

Even though it's not common, you do sometimes see "passers": here's a quotation about the UK Driving test:

> The study ... suggests that bad habits and over-confidence can lead first time passers to drive less safely ... [Source](https://www.wisedriving.com/blog/does-passing-test-first-time-make-better-driver)